# New line with string interpolation

Tags: c#

I try to get a new line between three properties. But I don't get a new line between the properties

Of course I googled it. But I tried with Environmen.newLine and with "\n". But non of this works

```
 $"Email: {teacher.EmailAddress}{Environment.NewLine} " +
                    $" Telefoonnummer: {teacher.PhoneNumber}  {Environment.NewLine}" +
                    $" Toelichting: {teacher.Explanation}" );
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. This code (with dummy variables) produces three separate lines.

Comment: where are you displaying it?

Comment: The code is clearly correct. How are you using it? It could be an interpretation problem somewhere else.

Comment: For reference, here's a simple dotnetfiddle of this code working in a `Console`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Zv4zR

Comment: What is the closing parenthesis for right before the semi-colon? I'm assuming it's just the end of a method call or something, but just checking.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$@` to use verbatim strings with interpolation (new lines are preserved)

```
$@"Email: {teacherCorrectionRequestDto.EmailAddress}
Telefoonnummer: {teacherCorrectionRequestDto.PhoneNumber}
Toelichting: {teacherCorrectionRequestDto.Explanation}"
```

Comment: Note that this has the downside that the line break you end up with is the line break of the source code at the time of compilation - *not* the natural line break for the environment the code is running in.

Comment: The properties are displayed in a readonly field. but oke. doesnt work

Comment: Oke, solved, Was an issue on the server side. So thank you all